# Hide all text in element if there is no child element through JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'll try to be concise for this weird issue.

I am hoping to hide text within a "p" tag if there's no child tag present within it.

As an example, if I have following:-

```
<p class="myflow"> Text <a href="#"> Some Link </a> </p>
```

I don't want anything to hide, but if there's following:-

```
<p class="myflow"> Text  </p>
```

Then I want "p.myflow" to hide, as there's no child tag.

I apologize for not writing some initial try, as I have no idea how to approach this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be this:

```
$('p.myflow:not(:has(*))').hide()
```

Comment: this does not hide 'p.myflow'

Comment: This hides the element if it **does** have something that isn't `*`. It doesn't hide it if it **doesn't** have anything.

Comment: That's better, you beat me to it.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( $('p.myflow').children().length < 1 ) {
       $('p.myflow').hide();
}
```

Comment: if that is the prerequisite, then consider using id not a class.

Comment: You could do this in a `.each()` loop that tests `$(this).children().length`

Comment: I wasn't describing a prerequisite, I was referring to your code. But my comment was incorrect because it [doesn't seem to work at all](http://jsfiddle.net/2n7uq63p/). Barmar has a hint.

Comment: again, your prerequisite is that you assume there will be more than one p.myflow. my prerequisite was that there is only one. try it with only one p.myflow and see if it does not work.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I did assume there was more than one.

Comment: Yes, using class usually means collection of elements, but in this question, it did not specify. I admit I wasn't all that careful about testing with more than one class of myflow